# Keyboard is moving view little too up

Tags: ios, swift

I made simple solution, textfield is pressed, open keyboard and move view up. But the problem is, it is moving it a little too hight and covering first `textField`. I do not want to make scrollView for this. is there any other solutions?

Like this I do what I described above:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RegisterViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RegisterViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }

    }


    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you can see what it does:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that a table view or just a simple view?

Comment: Does it happen on the first show or when you hide/show multiple times? Try   to remove your if statements and instead do this: self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height (show) and  self.view.frame.origin.y = 0 (hide)

Comment: It is jus view. It happens everytime I tap the textField. And your given solution didn't worked :( It does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options: for example:

- move the labels differently depending on the  texfield tapped (less if the first field, more for the last)
- change your Interface so that all your text fields use just the space available when keyboard is up

Answer (score -1):

There are many third party libraries available like https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager or https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding.

You can use any of them, and forgot about keyboard handling by yourself. These cool libraries take care of most of the things.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13912113)

Comment: @NSNoob Both of the above libraries, used by N number of people in N number of projects. Both these libraries just don't provide solution for above problem but also provide the answers for all type of keyboard related problems and used across worldwide. I think you must throw the correct answer, before giving negative rating to any person.

Comment: That doesn't matter mate. The policy is to provide solutions here, not links. Add links if you want, but add a programatical solution as well. Links can become invalid which make an entire answer invalid.